# How to simply cleanup a filename?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

OS: Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64

to display above:
`neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'`

.

How to simply cleanup a filename, not file contents?
by removing from a filename:

- `\n`  newlines
- `\t`  tabs
- non printable characters
- spaces

for microsoft windows no  `< > : " \ / | ? *`  in filename.

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon - sometimes works, but is actually NTFS Alternate Data Streams)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

.

Example 1:
How to make a problem filename.
Add a newline into a filename with mv
while at Terminal:

`touch a`

```
mv a $'b\nc'  # move (rename) files 
ls            # 'b'$'\n''c'
ls -b         # b\nc
```

with GUI, Press F2 = rename:

```
b
c
```

.

Example 2:
Longer name.

`touch 'This filename will have Tabs and Newlines_.txt'`

```
mv 'This filename will have Tabs and Newlines_.txt' $'This\tfilename\twill\thave\tTabs\nand\nNewlines_.txt'  
ls            # 'This'$'\t''filename'$'\t''will'$'\t''have'$'\n''Tabs'$'\n''and'$'\n''Newlines_.txt'
ls -b         # This\tfilename\twill\thave\nTabs\nand\nNewlines_.txt
```

with GUI, Press F2 = rename:

```
This    filename    will    have    Tabs
and
Newlines_.txt
```

.

Example 3:
More involved.
`touch 'This filename will have Tabs and Newlines & SPACES & colon: _.txt'`

```
mv 'This filename will have Tabs and Newlines & SPACES & colon: _.txt' $'This\tfilename\twill\thave\tTabs\nand\nNewlines & SPACES & colon: _.txt'
ls         # 'This'$'\t''filename'$'\t''will'$'\t''have'$'\t''Tabs'$'\n''and'$'\n''Newlines & SPACES & colon: _.txt'
ls -b      # This\tfilename\twill\thave\tTabs\nand\nNewlines\ &\ SPACES\ &\ colon:\ _.txt
```

with GUI, Press F2 = rename:

```
This    filename    will    have    Tabs
and
Newlines & SPACES & colon: _.txt
```

.

bash cleanup filename in Example 3:

```
#!/bin/bash   
clear
# FILE : original_filename comes from inotifywait command, On access, auto detect a file in /home/xxx/Downloads to eventually do a CLAM virus scan on FILE. 
filename1=$FILE
filename1=$'This\tfilename\twill\thave\tTabs\nand\nNewlines\ &\ SPACES\ &\ colon:\ _.txt'
echo "$filename1" 
filename2="${filename1//[$'\t'$'\n'$'\e'$'\r'$'\f'$'\v'$'\b'$'\a'$'\0']/-}"  # Replace Non Printable Characters with dash - 
echo "$filename2" 
filename3="${filename2//[$'\ ']/_}"    # Replace space with underscore _                                                   
echo "$filename3" 
filename4="${filename3//[$':']/_}"     # Replace colon : with underscore _                                                  
echo "$filename4"
```

.

bash result Example 3:

```
This    filename        will    have    Tabs
and
Newlines\ &\ SPACES\ &\ colon:\ _.txt  

This-filename-will-have-Tabs-and-Newlines\ &\ SPACES\ &\ colon:\ _.txt
This-filename-will-have-Tabs-and-Newlines__&__SPACES__&__colon:___.txt
This-filename-will-have-Tabs-and-Newlines__&__SPACES__&__colon____.txt
```

Replaced Non Printable Characters with dash - including

- `\n`  newlines
- `\t`  tabs
  Replaced space with underscore _
  Replaced colon `:` with underscore _

.

reference 1:
Full Non Printable Characters List
https://fjolt.com/article/linux-non-printable-characters

```
Name                 Binary  Decimal  Hexadecimal  Octal  Caret     Escape
                                                          Notation  Sequence  
Null               000 0000        0           00    000     ^@           \0 
Beep(BEL)          000 0111        7           07    007     ^G           \a 
Backspace(BS)      000 1000        8           08    010     ^H           \b        
HorizontalTab(HT)  000 1001        9           09    011     ^I           \t 
LineFeed(LF)       000 1010       10           0A    012     ^J           \n 
VerticalTab(VT)    000 1011       11           0B    013     ^K           \v 
FormFeed(FF)       000 1100       12           0C    014     ^L           \f 
CarriageReturn(CR) 000 1101       13           0D    015     ^M           \r 
Escape(ESC)        001 1011       27           1B    033     ^[           \e 

9 Escape Sequences:  
\0 
\a 
\b 
\t 
\n 
\v 
\f 
\r 
\e 


used: 
column -t -o '  ' a.txt b.txt
```

.

reference 2:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/general-10/remove-newline-and-tab-characters-from-filename-4175690259/

```
orig_filename=$'TN1\tThis\nFileName\nHas\tTabsandNewlines'
echo test > "$orig_filename"
new_filename="${orig_filename//[$'\t'$'\n']/-}"
mv --no-clobber "$orig_filename" "$new_filename"
```

.

reference 3:
Shell Parameter Expansion
${parameter//pattern/string}
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Question:
How to simply cleanup a filename?
What are the simpler commands?

--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an application like [detox](https://linux.die.net/man/1/detox) which has in-built sets of what you might want to clean. They are called [sequences](https://linux.die.net/man/5/detoxrc). Example usage:

```
detox -s safe -v /some/folder/or/file
```

This would only use a sequence that makes the name more safe for Unix usage. `-v` verbose flag accurately specifies the affected names.

You can also create your own combined sequences in `detoxrc` config file as described in the documentation above.

Comment: using GUI (graphical user interface), Dolphin, 
Press F2 rename, 
Ctrl-a = copy all the filename including 
```\n``` newlines and ```\t``` tabs _ 
```detox -s iso8859_1 -v 'This filename will have Tabs
and
Newlines & SPACES & colon: _.txt' ```
above filename was converted to: 
```This_filename_will_have_Tabs_and_Newlines_and_SPACES_and_colon_.txt ```  

detox command removed filename: 
```\n``` newlines, 
```\t``` tabs, 
```:``` colon, 
coverted SPACES to underscore _, 
converted ```&``` to ```and``` 
noting - file size remained the same.

Comment: ```detox -V```   # detox 1.4.5

Comment: Not quite sure what your comments mean. Are you asking for additional info or confirming it works for you?

Comment: Destroy666 typed: 
Are you asking for additional info? ```No.```  
Are you confirming it works for you? ```Yes.```  
detox version 1.4.5 works on test file in Example 3, 
resulting in : 
```This_filename_will_have_Tabs_and_Newlines_and_SPACES_and_colon_.txt ```  
i understand this site does not like comments relating to Thank You.

Comment: My comment confirms ```detox``` worked on 
one file in Example 3, is for 
you Destroy666 and for 
future readers so they have a possible solution with one example. 
Now, moving on to see how can i apply ```detox``` to a bash script doing 
auto detecting a file in /home/xxx/Downloads assigned 
```DIR1=$HOME/Downloads``` and to eventually do an automatic 
CLAM virus scan on FILE.